# How to rotate a cube using mouse in pyopengl

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I know what the problem is but i cannot figure out a solution. The problem is that the rotation is applied with the axis fixed on the cube so that if you turn one axis Pi radians then the other axis will look like the mouse controls are inverted. I want it to make it so clicking left mouse button and then moving the mouse to the right rotates the cube to the right, moving it to the left rotates the cube to the left, etc. Please help.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

vertices = ((-1, -1, -1), (-1, 1, -1), (-1, 1, 1), (-1, -1, 1), (1, -1, -1), (1, 1, -1), (1, 1, 1), (1, -1, 1))
edges = ((0, 1), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 2), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 5), (4, 7), (5, 6), (6, 7))
faces = ((0, 1, 2 , 3),(4,  5, 6, 7),(0, 4, 7, 3),(1, 5, 6, 2),(2, 6, 7, 3),(1, 5, 4, 0))

# =============================================================================
# vertices = ((1, -1, -1), (1, 1, -1), (-1, 1, -1), (-1, -1, -1), (1, -1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (-1, -1, 1), (-1, 1, 1))
# edges = ((0, 1), (0, 3), (0, 4), (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 7), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 7), (5, 1), (5, 4), (5, 7))
# =============================================================================

def Cube():
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    for face in faces:
        for vertex in face:
            glColor3fv((1, 0, 1))
            glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex])
    glEnd()

    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    glColor3fv((1, 1, 1))
    for edge in edges:
        for vertex in edge:
            glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex])
    glEnd()

def Main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = (1600, 1200)
    display = pygame.display.set_mode(screen, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)
    gluPerspective(45, (screen[0] / screen[1]), 0.1, 500)
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -5)
    button_down = False

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    glTranslatef(-1, 0, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    glTranslatef(1, 0, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    glTranslatef(0, 1, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    glTranslatef(0, -1, 0)
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                if button_down == True:
                    glRotatef(event.rel[1], 1, 0, 0)
                    glRotatef(event.rel[0], 0, 1, 0)
                print(event.rel)

        for event in pygame.mouse.get_pressed():
            print(pygame.mouse.get_pressed())
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1:
                button_down = True
            elif pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0:
                button_down = False

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        Cube()
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)

Main()
```

Comment: I think here it's not enough to just set the rotation, because you want it to rotate depending on the transformation of the cube vs the camera. To do this sort of thing you'll need to start looking at multiplying transformation matrices together, I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operations like [`glTranslated`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml) and [`glRotate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml) define a new matrix and multiply the current matrix by the new matrix.

```
finalmatrix = matrix1 * matrix2 * matrix3
```

If you want to apply the operations to the current model transformations than you have to do it in the reverse order.

```
finalmatrix = matrix3 * matrix2 * matrix1
```

In [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL), there are different current matrices (see [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml)). The matrices are organized on a stack. The matrices can be pushe on and popped from the stack by [`glPushMatrix` / `glPopMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml). This can be used to save and restore the matrices.

Apply the projection matrix to the projection matrix stack (`GL_PROJECTION`):

```py
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
gluPerspective(45, (screen[0] / screen[1]), 0.1, 500)
```

Switch to the model view matrix and store the current matrix to a variable `modelMatrix` at the begin this is the [`identity matrix`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix):

```py
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)  
modelMatrix= glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
```

In the loop:

- Store the model view matrix and lad the identity matrix:

```py
glPushMatrix()
glLoadIdentity()
```

- Do the new transformation (`glTranslatef` / `glRotatef`)
- Multiply the stored model view matrix and get then new final model view matrix

```py
glMultMatrixf(modelMatrix)
modelMatrix= glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
```

- Load the identity matrix set the view matrix and multiply the model view matrix:

```py
glLoadIdentity()
glTranslatef(0, 0, -5)
glMultMatrixf(modelMatrix)
```

- Draw the model and restore the current matrix

```py
Cube()
glPopMatrix()
```

See the example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

vertices = ((-1, -1, -1), (-1, 1, -1), (-1, 1, 1), (-1, -1, 1), (1, -1, -1), (1, 1, -1), (1, 1, 1), (1, -1, 1))
edges = ((0, 1), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 2), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 5), (4, 7), (5, 6), (6, 7))
faces = ((0, 1, 2 , 3),(4,  5, 6, 7),(0, 4, 7, 3),(1, 5, 6, 2),(2, 6, 7, 3),(1, 5, 4, 0))

# =============================================================================
# vertices = ((1, -1, -1), (1, 1, -1), (-1, 1, -1), (-1, -1, -1), (1, -1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (-1, -1, 1), (-1, 1, 1))
# edges = ((0, 1), (0, 3), (0, 4), (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 7), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 7), (5, 1), (5, 4), (5, 7))
# =============================================================================

def Cube():
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    for face in faces:
        for vertex in face:
            glColor3fv((1, 0, 1))
            glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex])
    glEnd()

    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    glColor3fv((1, 1, 1))
    for edge in edges:
        for vertex in edge:
            glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex])
    glEnd()

def Main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = (1600, 1200)
    display = pygame.display.set_mode(screen, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    gluPerspective(45, (screen[0] / screen[1]), 0.1, 500)
    button_down = False

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)  
    modelMatrix = glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)

    while True:
        glPushMatrix()
        glLoadIdentity()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    glTranslatef(-1, 0, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    glTranslatef(1, 0, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    glTranslatef(0, 1, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    glTranslatef(0, -1, 0)
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                if button_down == True:
                    glRotatef(event.rel[1], 1, 0, 0)
                    glRotatef(event.rel[0], 0, 1, 0)
                print(event.rel)

        for event in pygame.mouse.get_pressed():
            print(pygame.mouse.get_pressed())
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1:
                button_down = True
            elif pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0:
                button_down = False

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        glMultMatrixf(modelMatrix)
        modelMatrix = glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)

        glLoadIdentity()
        glTranslatef(0, 0, -5)
        glMultMatrixf(modelMatrix)

        Cube()

        glPopMatrix()
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)

Main()
```